# how to get value in other div i'm just start to learn python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```py
map_tags = web_bs4.find_all("section", {"class": "relative mb-8 max-md:mb-8"})
            if len(map_tags) >= 3:
              map_tag = map_tags[2]
              map = map_tag.get_text().replace("\n", "")
            else:
              map = "-"
```

i'm try to learn datascraping a can get all value but i can't get a this latitude , longtitude it's just show a h2 value how to get value in div class text-xs mt-2 ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGw1Z.png)

Comment: i'm just get ทำเลที่ตั้ง value but i want to get lat,lon pls

Comment: Could you please provide from what page the web scraping being done?

Comment: https://propertyscout.co.th/%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%82%E0%B8%94-3-%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99-mykonos-huahin-%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%9A-%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%94%E0%B9%82%E0%B8%95%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B8%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%99-1292390/


i'm just test to get data on google colab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

response = requests.get('https://propertyscout.co.th/%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%82%E0%B8%94-3-%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99-mykonos-huahin-%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%9A-%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%94%E0%B9%82%E0%B8%95%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B8%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%99-1292390/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', attrs={'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'}).text)
relevant_data = data['props']['pageProps']['property']
print(relevant_data['gpsLong'], relevant_data['gpsLat'])
```

Comment: Glad it helped! You can select the answer as accepted and/or vote it up if it works for you.